# In vim with c.vim, how to jump to next position when using the code generation function

Tags: vim

when type \ss in the normal mode,it generated code as follows

```
   char c ='b';
   switch ( c ) {
    case <-LABEL->: 
    break;
   }
```

how do i jump to position "LABEL" when i finished input "c"

the key "TAB" doesn't work...

Comment: Which mapping is behind `\ss`? Do you use a snippet plugin?

Comment: what do you mean? while c.vim is a snippet plugin for c & c++

Comment: This mapping does not come with Vim. You must have installed a plugin. I guess you mean [this](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=213).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless the plugin provides a mapping for this (have you read its documentation?), the quickest way to change the placeholder would be `/<-<CR>cf>` (search for the start of the placeholder and change until the end of it). You could abbreviate that with a `:nnoremap` mapping.

Comment: well, i solve it. the shortcut key is <c+j>....you give me some advice to my previous questions.Are you always keep active on the vim channel?

Comment: Ah, good you found it. I looked at the plugin's documentation, but it was pretty complex (like the entire plugin), and I didn't find anything.

Comment: By looking at the Vim questions, I'm learning a lot for myself, too. It's a mutual benefit for both sides: win-win :-)